# PHP uploading a file to slack api

Tags: php, api, slack

I am using the Slack Web API Wrapper (https://github.com/palanik/slack-php) trying to upload files to the slack api with the files->upload function with multipart/form-data . However, I only get a error message: "no_file_data".

Here is my code:

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
$slack = new wrapi\slack\slack('api-key');

$file = new CurlFile(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dir/dir/test.jpg'), 'image/png');

$id = 'XXXX'; 

$reply = $slack->files->upload
(
    [
        [
            'name' => 'file.jpg',
            'channel' => $id,
            'file' => $file,
            'filetype' => 'jpg',
            'filename' => 'test.jpg'
        ]
    ]
);
```

**Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?** I have tried review the other threads here... The test.jpg-file is not the error source.